# Modify pseoduclass to either of two options based on class name

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to modify the 'button-transparent:before' attribute based on if the button has a wishlist class or not. The sass below does not seem to work

```
<button
    className={classnames(
        'button--transparent',
        {'wishlist icon--heart-filled': props.wishlisted},
        {'icon--heart': !props.wishlisted},
    )}
    onClick={props.toggle}
>
    ...
</button>
```

sass

```
.button--transparent {
  $color: initial;
  .wishlist & {
    $color: #EE4444;
  }

  &:before {
    color: $color !important
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the `:before` pseudo element when the dom element has classes `.button--transparent` and also `.wishlist` then the sass should look like this:

```
.button--transparent {
  $color: initial;
  &.wishlist {
    $color: #EE4444;
    &:before {
     color: $color !important
    }
  }  
}
```